# How to call function inside directive from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, directive

I would like to call function from parent inside my directive which have own controller.

//parent

```
angular
    .module('app.test')
    .controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.changeTest = changeTest;

        function changeTest() {
          console.log("ssss")
        }
})



<div>
  <div app-count count="changeTest()"></div>
</div>
```

//child

```
angular
    .module('app.test')
    .directive('appCount', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/core/count/count.directive.html',
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                count: '&',
            },
            controller: 'AppCountController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        };
    })
    .controller('AppCountController', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.clickMe = clickMe;

        function clickMe() {
          $scope.count()
        }


    })
})


<button ng-click="vm.clickMe()">Click</button>
```

So i thought if I use something like below, I could call function $scope.count() but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it is because your `count="changeTest()"` is looking for `$scope.changeText()` .. You need to write `count="vm.changeTest()"` to use `$scope.vm.changeTest()`, supposing you used the syntax `ng-controller="X as vm"` before.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still doesn't work.

Comment: declare the function changeText first, then use `$scope.changeText = changeText;` (or even `$scope.changeText = fn() { ... }`), then continue to use `count="changeTest()"`. It should work like this.